# Accessing resource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**I know this is simple but I am very new in XAML.**

I have two folders in my solutions
Resources\Images\font.png
Shapes\dictonary1.xaml
the soultion also has app.xaml and mainwindow.xaml

```
            <Label ToolTip="Label">
                <Label.Background>
                     <ImageBrush ImageSource="\Resources\Images\Font.png" />
                </Label.Background>
            </Label>
```

In my dictonary1.xaml file I add a label containing a background brush
But throws me an error

This work fine in wen I do the same in MainWindow.xaml file.

The font.png file properties
Build action is Resource and
Copy to output directory is always Copy always

I hope I am clear

Comment: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '282' and line position '22'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you merge dictionary1.xaml into the mainwindow.xaml? If the image is used in dictionary1.xaml then try this:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="../Resources/Images/Font.png" />
```

Comment: yes I have merged the dicitinary1.xaml in mainwindow.xaml.
 wirting the <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Resources/Images/Font.png" /> also throws me the error